# Laravel get ID of newly created resource

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-6

So basically I am doing this:

```
Laptop::create([
    'user_id' => 1,
    'name' => $request->name,
    'brand' => $request->brand,
    'SN' => $request->SN,
    'price' => $request->price
]);
```

How do I save the ID of the newly created resource? Since the ID field is auto incrementing I don't need to insert it manually. If for example the ID is 47, I need to be able to store the ID locally for use. Like store it in a variable named `$ID`

This is so I can create meta rows which contain information on the Laptop like Laptop parts. They all need a parent_id which would be the `$ID`

Comment: This is gonna get downvoted for shitty wording but I can't explain it very hard to do man

Comment: Do you have relations set up between the two models? https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-relationships#inserting-and-updating-related-models

Comment: Just so you know, the rest of the question is actually irrelevant, I only need to retrieve the ID of the newly created ```Laptop``` and store it locally so I don't get any conflictions

Comment: If you have relations set up you don't even need the id, create the Laptop, create its Preset relation. Done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$id = Laptop::lastInsertId();
```

or

```
$id = Laptop::create([
    'user_id' => 1,
    'name' => $request->name,
    'brand' => $request->brand,
    'SN' => $request->SN,
    'price' => $request->price
])->id;
```

Answer (score 4):

Create will return object of `Laptop` model.

```
$laptop = Laptop::create([
 'user_id' => 1,
 'name' => $request->name,
 'brand' => $request->brand,
 'SN' => $request->SN,
 'price' => $request->price
]);

$id = $laptop->id;
```

OR

```
  $laptop = Laptop::create([
 'user_id' => 1,
 'name' => $request->name,
 'brand' => $request->brand,
 'SN' => $request->SN,
 'price' => $request->price
])->id;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$laptop = Laptop::create([
    'user_id' => 1,
    'name' => $request->name,
    'brand' => $request->brand,
    'SN' => $request->SN,
    'price' => $request->price
]);

$id = $laptop->id;
```

Answer (score 1):

To get recently Added id you may follow this code

```
$laptop = Laptop::create([
    'user_id' => 1,
    'name' => $request->name,
    'brand' => $request->brand,
    'SN' => $request->SN,
    'price' => $request->price
]);

$id = $laptop->id;  //You get recently added id
echo $id;
```

Comment: please select this answer if it is helpful for you

Answer (score 1):

The `create` method returns the saved model instance. So use it link this:

```
$laptop = Laptop::create([
    'user_id' => 1,
    'name' => $request->name,
    'brand' => $request->brand,
    'SN' => $request->SN,
    'price' => $request->price
]);

$id = $laptop->id;
```

`$id` is required id of newly added data.